# Reg Ex - Find all integers in string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a following value "1pm 2am" that I'm using a regular expression againts in SSIS to extract hours from in order to store separately. I've tried using both of the regular expressions below but both only yield the first number "1".

```
"(\d+)"
"(\*?\d{1,2}\*?)"
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can there ever be non-integers in your string that you want to avoid matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Regex.matches` instead of `Regex.match`. `Regex.matches` returns a collection of all matches. `Your regex can just be`\d+` by itself.